# When is $ax + bx + cx \equiv y \pmod{26}$ an invertible function?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, inverse

Say we have some encryption function that encrypts $x$ into $y$ with keys $a,b,c$ using the formula $ax + bx + cx \equiv y \pmod{26}$. All $a,b,c,x,y \in \{0, ..., 25\}$. By invertible, I mean that there should be some $d,e,f \in \{0, ..., 25\}$ such that $dy + ey + fy \equiv x \pmod{26}$ for all possible $x,y$.

For this to be invertible, I believe it is enough to expect that this function is one-to-one and onto. Clearly this is not true for all $a,b,c$. Is there any generalization we can make for $a,b,c$ for this to hold?

Comment: How about imagining $a+b+c$ has common divisor with 26?

Comment: @Nightflight very interesting, thank you! by the same principle, this should also hold if we use more keys in the same pattern, say $ax + bx + cx + dx$ by maintaining that $a+b+c+d$ also should be relatively prime to 26?

Comment: this really became much easier once I realized factoring out the x gives you $x*(a+b+c)$

Comment: Yes, it does. every number relative prime with 26 $m$ has its *inverse*, such that $m\times i_m \equiv1 \pmod 26$.